# Jira jql query to filter issues which has child issue in it

Tags: jira, project-management, jql, jira-agile

I am in a situation where I have a Basic JQL i.e.

`issueKey in (JIRA-1,JIRA-2,...JIRA-1000)`

I would like to add a **AND** condition and filter out the only issues which has Child issues within

Expected Output - If JIRA-1,JIRA-2 only has child issues so the query should return JIRA-1 and JIRA-2 out of issue keys

Why this is needed - In long running project backlog I want to get issue filter to not to miss the child issues to be prioritised

Comment: I suspect this is going to be difficult without a JIRA plugin like ScriptRunner or JQL Tricks.

Comment: Ok. I haven't used any of mentioned plugins before and not very sure if they will be that easy to add up in org level. Thanks for the suggestion mate. will keep this question open to try luck

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because your project is at a too high level since subtasks are usually just for developers to break down their work.

It also sounds that you are not prioritizing properly since you have the need to look below the user stories.

If you have the need to focus on subtasks inside a 3-week user story I suggest you break them out, so you can prioritize properly.

You can just sort on subtasks and prioritize them separately if you like?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ScriptRunner installed on your instance, you can add this JQL Query `issueFunction in hasLinkType("Parent-Child")`